# Regex from " 1" to "15"

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex matching a num in a log file from " 1" to "15", not from "1" to 15", because in my file:

- April _1
- April _2
- ..
- April 10
- April 11

with a space (symbolize by "_") in place of the first digit where there is no one.

I tried: `grep 'Sep  [1-9]|1[0-2]'`
but it seems to not match with the " "

Comment: *from " 1" to "15", not from "1" to 15"*, what? xd

Comment: It doesn't work because an April isn't a September.

Comment: A link that might be useful to convert a range to regex: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: just a mistake while typing my question, I'm right looking for April

Answer (score 4):

`April ( [1-9]|1[0-5])`

(two spaces after "April" for 1-9, one space for 10-15)

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
grep -E 'Sep[[:blank:]]([[:blank:]][1-9]|1[0-5])' file
```

This will match

```
Sep  1
Sep  2
Sep  3
...
...
Sep 10
Sep 11
...
...
Sep 15
```

Comment: What's the difference between `:blank:` and `\s`?

Comment: `\s` is PCRE property that matches space, tab or newline whereas `[[:blank:]]` is POSIX class that matches space or tab only. `\s` doesn't work on all Unix flavors.

Comment: Hmm your question says: **I'm looking for a regex that matching num in a log file from " 1" to "15"**. For `10` to `15` use: `grep -E 'Sep[[:blank:]]+1[0-5]' file`

Answer (score 0):

April[ _]{1,2}((1)[0-5]{1}|[0-5]{1})